# Triac BT 136 not working with load connected to MT1 terminal but working with load in MT2 Terminal

Tags: mosfet, analog, power-electronics, switching, triac

Triac BT  136 not working with load connected to MT1 terminal..

but working with load in MT2 Terminal.

Please see the below connection diagram in working and non working cases.

If its bidirectional device(like a mecanical switch or relay), when load connected in MT1 or MT2 terminal it should work..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show the circuit with the load connected to MT2. You are doing something wrong.

Comment: This will work but if you switch lamp to Mt1 it will not.

Comment: please draw the circuit - you are doing something wrong. For example, where does the negative terminal of the battery connect?

Comment: Please see the above update.

Comment: that is what I expected you were doing wrong. Also even in your working arrangement, the triac is functioning bidirectionally as the power input is AC.

Answer (score 1):

[image: triac3]

It works, but in both cases the Gate current must be switched relative to MT1.

Comment: Please see the above update and explain whats wrong in this approach.Its bidirectional device.Like mechanical relay or mechanical switch, where load can be connected any connection terminal for load switching.

Comment: @Electron Your second version can only work if the voltage Vg is so high that it can generate the required Gate current through the lamp resistor. In your first version, 3V is enough to turn on the triac. You may need much more than the second version (depending on the lamp). However, if you turn it on, it will ruin your switch circuit because the full mains voltage will be applied to Vg. Always turn on relative to MT1, then the same voltage need to switch on. As you can see in my second drawing.